# Image getting shrink and display in middle of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Here the image is getting very small. and i also want to align image in centre .pLEASE tell some solution so that image is in centre and is shown in original size. I'm using bootstrap.

```
    <div class="container" style="height: 100%;">

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="height: 100%;display: table;">

                <a href="machine1.php" style="display : table-cell;vertical-align: middle;">

                    <img src="ft/text.png" class="img-responsive" style="min-width:660px;">
                </a>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">



            </div>
```

```
.body-wrapper {
            background: url('slide2_2.png');
            background-size: cover;
            height:100%;
        }
            html, body{
            height:100%; 
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            color:white;
        }

            a:hover{
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .img-responsive{
                float: left;
            }
```

Wnat imag to be in vertcal and horizontal centre and image size is 1366* 635

Comment: Can you make it more clear what you want to achieve? What size is the image or what size you want it to be? You want to center it how, where? Horizontally in the body element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ws4n0kh0/

try this.

```
<div class="container" style="height: 100%;">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="height: 100%;display: table; width:100%">
    <a href="machine1.php" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
      <img src="https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chuck/lennapg/len_std.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
</div>
```

Also removed img-responsive from CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want here
Try this if you want the image in the center

https://jsfiddle.net/0fcpr65u/4/

```
<div class="container" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="text-align:center">
            <a href="machine1.php">
                <img src="http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/01-2014/2-flower-wallpaper.preview.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:200px;margin: auto;">
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

remove float from the image css

EDIT:
I f you want it to be at the center of the page
add width & height to parent div make there position relative

Add this to the image

```
width: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: calc(50% - 100px);
left: calc(50% - 100px);
```

or you can use vertically-align property by using display:table

If you want the original size of the image use this

```
<div class="container" style="height: 100%;">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="height: 100%;display: table; width:100%">
    <a href="machine1.php" style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
      <img  src="http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/01-2014/2-flower-wallpaper.preview.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
</div>
```

Else use flex

by adding this css in parent div

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: thanx for quick reply ......image is still small and sticking to top of screen i want img in middle of screen in centre with full size

Comment: i juts tried my code and it keeps the image at the center and you can change the size by using width

Comment: added jsFiddle link you can check that

Comment: verically middle also

Comment: Why are you using table and table-cells for <a> element? Wouldn't it be easier to just use a flexbox <div> ?

Comment: @AmmarAjmal used code img is in centre but image is shrinked very vech

Comment: @smarttechy you can increase the size of the image from css
Or if you want to use the original size then use the second code i gave

Comment: your second solution is giving a horizontal scroll to the screen

Comment: @smarttechy dude, maybe give a logical description of what you actually want, and then we will be able to help. Your code is really chaotic, inline styles mixed with css so not sure what you actually want to stay and what can be removed... Does it have to be a bootstrap column? Does it have to be .img-responsive class? can it be a flexbox?

Comment: @Varin i just need the background image and the inside image to be responsive . bootstrap can be removed  .. i have no knowledge about flexbox whats that

Comment: @smarttechy Have you checked my answer below?